# How to connect to MySQL via Python when the database can only be accessed via a jumphost

Tags: python, mysql, ssh-tunnel

I have a MySQL database which is accessible only via a jumphost. Topology in which we are trying to access MySQL is as follows

Client Host -> jumphost -> MySQL

MySQL is accessed by SSL port forwarding using the following command
ssh -At -L 3306:MySQL:3306 user@jumphost

Once the tunnel is created, connection to MySQL from Workbench running on the client host is successful with host as localhost and port 3306.

But if I try to access MySQL using the same connection properties (host: localhost, port: 3306) via pymysql module of mysql the following error occurs
OperationalError: (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' ([Errno 99] Cannot assign requested address)")

Code details:

```
import pymysql
import pandas

def getQueryResult(query):
    host = 'localhost';
    password = 'something';
    database = 'test';

    conn = pymysql.connect(host=host, port=int(3306), user="someuser", passwd=password, db=database);
    df = pandas.read_sql_query(query, conn);
    conn.close();
    return df;
```

We expect the connection to be established successfully but instead we get an error with the trace

```
OSErrorTraceback (most recent call last)
/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py in connect(self, sock)
    957                                 (self.host, self.port), self.connect_timeout,
--> 958                                 **kwargs)
    959                             break

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/socket.py in create_connection(address, timeout, source_address)
    723     if err is not None:
--> 724         raise err
    725     else:

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/socket.py in create_connection(address, timeout, source_address)
    712                 sock.bind(source_address)
--> 713             sock.connect(sa)
    714             # Break explicitly a reference cycle

OSError: [Errno 99] Cannot assign requested address

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
```

My Code callstack: Omitting these frames

```
/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymysql/__init__.py in Connect(*args, **kwargs)
     88     """
     89     from .connections import Connection
---> 90     return Connection(*args, **kwargs)
     91 
     92 from . import connections as _orig_conn

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py in __init__(self, host, user, password, database, port, unix_socket, charset, sql_mode, read_default_file, conv, use_unicode, client_flag, cursorclass, init_command, connect_timeout, ssl, read_default_group, compress, named_pipe, no_delay, autocommit, db, passwd, local_infile, max_allowed_packet, defer_connect, auth_plugin_map, read_timeout, write_timeout, bind_address, binary_prefix)
    702             self._sock = None
    703         else:
--> 704             self.connect()
    705 
    706     def _create_ssl_ctx(self, sslp):

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py in connect(self, sock)
   1003                 exc.traceback = traceback.format_exc()
   1004                 if DEBUG: print(exc.traceback)
-> 1005                 raise exc
   1006 
   1007             # If e is neither DatabaseError or IOError, It's a bug.

OperationalError: (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' ([Errno 99] Cannot assign requested address)")
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use the SSH Tunnel from python as explain here: https://medium.com/@amirziai/query-your-database-over-an-ssh-tunnel-with-pandas-603ce49b35a1

Comment: And using the pymysql lib in python code

 - see: [https://pypi.org/project/PyMySQL/][1]
 - docs: [https://pymysql.readthedocs.io/en/latest/][2]

I hope it helps


  [1]: https://pypi.org/project/PyMySQL/
  [2]: https://pymysql.readthedocs.io/en/latest/